# Selenium Wbdriver testing for different locales

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, domain-driven-design, testng

I don't have solid experience in Selenium for multilocal applications. My question relates to localization testing via Selenium Webdriver, Java, TestNG, Ant.

What I have - Java Application with 9 Locales distinguished by particular URL. Every culture has it's own language, and a little differences in functionality. I've created test suite with acceptance tests for English version only using Page Object pattern. Data for tests are not organized well: some constants, some separate data classes....

My question is how to organize test data: inputs, queries, client data to have different sets for each locale. How to run tests for each locale one by one? Is it possible to specify different urls in testng.xml - any samples are welcome.

To sum up I want to clarify the following:

- Data organization when we have one test suite for all locales with different test data.
- MultiURLs tests running: testng.xml, build.xml...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the functionality was the same, the pages were always the same except the texts were in different languages.

So most of the ids, xpath expressions and commands stayed the same and I only needed to switch between the different localized messages and texts. For that, I used the same files that are used by the website itself to switch locales - in my case `applicationResources.properties` accesible perfectly by [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) - you can load the right file based on the URL at the start of the test and you're basically done.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using properties too and it contains: login, password, url, driver type. Could you provide a switching sample?